# Can I control a motor in both directions using two sets of dry contacts

Tags: dc-motor, short-circuit, polarity

Using a device like a Shelly Uni, which has controllable sets of dry contacts, can two sets of dry contacts be used to run an electric motor in either direction, using only one power source?

Ie, assume that positive power is connected to side A of the motor, and the negative is connected via one set of dry contacts to side B of the motor. To operate in the reverse direction would require positive to be connected via another set of dry contacts to side B of the motor. The corollary is that negative would have to be connected to side A of the motor, which already has positive connected to it, which is a short.

Are there any simple circuit options to allow this to work?

Edit: Below is a diagram of the Shelly Uni to illustrate what I mean by sets of dry contacts. https://kb.shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/shelly-uni

[image]

Comment: what exactly is a `set of contacts` ... please draw a diagram, or say what type of switch/switches it represents

Comment: I have added a diagram of the Shelly Uni showing it's two sets of outputs, and a URL for the knowledgebase for this device.

Comment: "dry contacts" is a pretty standard term, it is well understood. Typically just connections for a switch or a relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this with two dry contacts would be to use a DPCO relay to set direction, and control that with one dry contact. The other dry contact is used for on/off. Like this:

[image: schematic]

Protection diodes, etc, not shown.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Does the DPCO relay need to have six pins as depicted in your drawing? Googling tells me DPDT relays are the same thing as DPCO, and some of them have six pins and some have four...

Comment: I can't see how a DPCO can have less than eight - 3 for each set of contacts, 2 for the coil. Can you link to one that has four? That sounds like single pole. A DPDT switch would have six.

Comment: Oops I was looking at the relay in profile, yes it has eight pins.

Comment: What is a "DPCO" relay?  I read that as "Double Pole Center Off" - I've never seen a relay that will do that.  I would call the relay in your diagram "DPDT"

Comment: Double Pole Change Over

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with two SPDT relays:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl6nUg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used a lamp to represent the motor, as I couldn't find a motor in CircuitLab.

With both relays released, both sides of the motor will be Grounded, so it won't run.  Likewise, with both relays operated, both sides of teh motor will be at +12V, so it won't run.

With either the "Forward" or "Reverse" leads grounded, one relay will operate and that side of the motor will be connected to the positive supply, so the motor will run in one direction.

As the Shelley outputs appear to be simple normally-open contacts, you will need additional relays that will be controlled through the Shelley contacts.

Answer (score -1):

The usual way to do reversing is with an [H-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge), which takes four relays.  If you're open to adding an additional part you can get an H-bridge IC and control that with your dry contacts.

Your dry contacts are only spec'd to handle 100 mA, which is likely less than your motor will want.  So you'd probably need some additional driver anyways.

Comment: The motor is a tiny 6v one with low RPM. Its specs didn't even say how many amps it needs. Looking at similar motors online they are 50 to 100mA. I'll put the multimeter across it tomorrow and see how many amps it's drawing. The motor is running fine through the Shelly Uni's contacts